# Javadoc Exclude causing errors on import

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I'm looking to tweak the javadocs for the library my company produces. We're looking to exclude javadocs from classes that aren't really meant for public consumption (mostly classes used internally).

The project uses gradle as the build system, and I've marked the packages/classes that we want to exclude in the build.gradle file. However, this is causing errors to happen. I expect to get a warning, or error if there's @link to a class which is excluded, but it's also throwing errors when those excluded classes are simply imported. Is there a way to "include" the classes/packages, but NOT export the javadoc for them?

Edit: Here's the relevant javadoc task:

```
task gendocs(type: Javadoc) {
    options.stylesheetFile = new File("./assets/doc_style.css")
    String v = "${SEMVER}"
    version = v.replace("_", '.')
    title = "SweetBlue ${version} API"
    options.windowTitle = "SweetBlue"
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
    options.author = true
    options.linksOffline('http://d.android.com/reference', System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + '/docs/reference')    
    destinationDir = new File("${BUNDLE_FOLDER}/docs/api")
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath += configurations.compile
    exclude "com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/backend"
    exclude "com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/utils/Utils**.java"
    exclude "com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/utils/UpdateLoop.java"
    exclude "com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/utils/Pointer.java"
    exclude "com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/utils/HistoricalDataQuery.java"
}
```

Edit 2: Here's the error I'm talking about:

```
SweetBlue/src/com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/BleCharacteristic.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.idevicesinc.sweetblue.utils.Utils;                                      
symbol:   class Utils
location: package com.idevicesinc.sweetblue.utils
```

Edit 3:

It appears that exclude in a gradle javadoc task is NOT the same thing as using -exclude on the command line with javadoc. I ran a test using CLI javadoc generation, and I did NOT get the not found errors that I do when using Gradle.

---

I have also [posted this on the Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/javadoc-exclusion-question/11875) but did not receive an answer there.

Comment: How can someone diagnose what's happening when you provide no details on what errors you're getting?  It may not matter, but I doubt the "Utils**.java" pattern is doing anything useful.  That likely should be just "Utils*.java".

Comment: I  updated the OP with the error I was referring to. I suppose I wasn't clear enough before. What I have for Utils works just fine (there are multiple classes which start with Utils). They are properly excluded.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  Post a detailed note on the Gradle forum.

Comment: @RyanBis Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, other than to just generate the javadocs on the command line, rather than through gradle. I've even posted on the Gradle forums, and only got crickets.

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc needs to know about the imported class. Tell javadoc where to find the class files rather than the java source code with the classpath!

I had the same problem with XJC generated code that generates numerous javadoc errors in an ant environment.
In order to exclude them from docs but still satisfy javadoc I simply told the javadoc task to look into the bin folder:

```
<target name="javadoc" description="create Javadoc documentation">
    <javadoc ...lots of irrelevant attributes skipped...>
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="my/jaxb/generated/source/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="myclasspath_to_referenced_libraries"/>
            <pathelement location="bin"/>
        </classpath>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you have to tell the Javadoc task where the external imports are located, so it can creates (Hyper)-links to it in the Javadoc HTML. If you don't care about links to external classes you could ignore theses issues with:

```
task gendocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    ...
}
```

According to the [Gradle Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:failOnError):

> Specifies whether this task should fail when errors are encountered during Javadoc generation. When true, this task will fail on Javadoc error. When false, this task will ignore Javadoc errors

Comment: Used this suggestion, but the generated documentation was corrupted

Comment: @RudyBarbieri makes sense if you disable fail check, that your output might be corrupt. You problem is in your javadoc - there is something in it that Leads it to make illegal html. Just check the error output what’s wrong.

Comment: I have this set, and I am only including one file. But it still does not generate the output, saying that a package was not found. (It is a package that my only included file imports at the top, for which I do not want to generate Javadoc output.)